# d3-geo-projection es6 imports

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've started using ES6 imports in my projects and Id like to import d3-geo-projection in such a way that I can call the extra projections as I always have, as in:

```
var proj = d3.geoAitoff();
```

And I'd like to avoid rolling my own bundle.

I have tried

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import 'd3-geo-projection';
```

And I tried

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {geoAitoff} from 'd3-geo-projection';
```

Neither results in being able to call var `proj = d3.geoAitoff()`;

Can anyone advise on how this should be done?

Comment: `var proj = geoAitoff()`

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
import {geoAitoff} from "d3-geo-projection";

var projection = geoAitoff();
```